# Excel report exported from SSRS 2012 - Unable to finding the empty cells

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report in SSRS which has around 70 columns and 2000 rows. it contains few empty cells (not empty rows/columns). After downloading the report from SSRS to excel, I am trying to find the empty cells using Ctrl+F, it is not finding the empty cells. I tried by moving the cursor in a column by pressing Ctrl+Down arrow key to jump to to next empty cell which is also not working, directly cursor jumping to the last cell though it has many empty cells in between. Any fix/solution to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Thanks
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

I Google'ed "Excel find empty cell"
I found the answer immediately:

> To select the empty cells, use Excel's built in Go To Special feature:
>   Select columns A and B, that contain the blank cells. On the Ribbon's
>   Home tab, click Find & Select. Click Go To Special. In the Go To
>   Special dialog box, click Blanks, then click OK.

Comment: Thanks, But it is not capturing the blank cells, It is going directly to the end of the last row.Also I tried by click ctrl+F (find) which is also not finding the empty cells. But I have empty cells in my excel and I checked the length of the cell as well which is zero.